Using sed to change the field delimiter comma to TAB
I have a bunch of Gzip-compressed CSV files which are separated by comma delimiters as show below:
"000001","SessionID_11111",,,,"[{""c1"":""v1"",""c2"":""v2"",""c3"":""v3""}]",,,,"{""products"":[{""c1"":""v1"",""c2"":""v2"",""c3"":""v3""}]}","{}",,1,2,,,

What I want to do is convert comma delimiter to TAB, while preserving those within JSON/Array documents like this:
"000001"\t"SessionID_11111"\t\t\t\t"[{""c1"":""v1"",""c2"":""v2"",""c3"":""v3""}]"\t\t\t\t"{""products"":[{""c1"":""v1"",""c2"":""v2"",""c3"":""v3""}]}"\t"{}"\t\t1\t2\t\t\t

Those JSON/Array fields are making weird and unwanted output.
How can I get the good output?

use unused chars (~, ^, etc.) to save state, alog w/ pipes

better to use c or awk

sed is the wrong tool for anything involving fields as it doesn't have a concept of fields. awk, the other mandatory POSIX text processing tool, does work on field though. Uncompress the file fist then, using any awk, awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(/,/,"\t",$i)} 1' file will do what you want since the fact the quoted fields contain JSON is irrelevant, they're just quoted fields containing ,s in a CSV. If you need to do anything more than just that to it, though, then you should probably use a tool like python that understands both CSV and JSON.
